# URLencoding of CSR

Tags: linux

I am trying to encode the CSR (Certificate Signing Request) in a Linux environment but I am not getting correct output.

The command I used

```
urlencode -m csr
```

Comment: Ok. What *is* your expected output? Please edit your question to make it easier to answer. Provide both input and output (if possible) and the expected results.

Answer (score 2):

per the [manual page for `urlencode`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/urlencode), the arguments to the command are strings, not filenames.

To `urlencode` the contents of the file `csr` and leave the results in `csr.enc`, you could use shell substitution and redirection as

```
$ urlencode -m $(<csr) > csr.enc
```